# Cannot update model when passing it to a function

Tags: angularjs

I am using extra function to handle keyboard input. It seems that value gets passed successfully but when I try to assign like this `model += char;` value it fails. Why?

```
$scope.keyboardBtn = function(char){

        if($scope.focusedInput.name == 'inputFirstName'){
            $scope.keyboardAction($scope.persons[$scope.focusedInput.row].firstName, char);
        }
    };
    $scope.keyboardAction = function (model, char) {
        if(char == 'SPACE'){char = ' '}
        if(char == 'CLEAR'){
            if(model.length > 0){
                model = model.substr(0, model.length -1 );   // fails
            }
        }else{
            model += char; // fails
        }
    };

<button type="button" ng-click="keyboardBtn('SPACE')">SPACE</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="keyboardBtn('Z')">Z</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="keyboardBtn('CLEAR')">CLEAR</button>
```

Comment: Could you post html code behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is always pass by value, any changes in a function would not affect the original value. (Please reference this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6605640/232710)).

To achieve what you want, you can pass the object(`$scope.persons[$scope.focusedInput.row]`) instead of the attribute(`$scope.persons[$scope.focusedInput.row].firstName`) and change the attribute value in the function. For example:

```
$scope.keyboardBtn = function(char){
    if($scope.focusedInput.name == 'inputFirstName'){
        $scope.keyboardAction($scope.persons[$scope.focusedInput.row], char);
    }
};

$scope.keyboardAction = function (model, char) {
    if(char == 'SPACE'){char = ' '}
    if(char == 'CLEAR'){
        if(model.firstName.length > 0){
            model.firstName = model.firstName.substr(0, model.length -1 );
        }
    }else{
        model.firstName += char;
    }
};
```